# What is the R equivalent of Matlab's fminunc function?

Tags: r, matlab, math, mathematical-optimization

In order to compute the optimal theta e.g. in logistic regression, I have to create a costFunction (the function to be minimized) which is then passed to fminunc in order to obtain the optimal theta.
Also, if the gradient of costFunction can be computed, I set the 'GradObj' option to 'on' using

```
options = optimset('GradObj','on');
```

and code the costFunction so that it returns, as a second output argument, the gradient value g of X.
Then I give

```
[theta, cost] = fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)), initial_theta, options);
```

where X is the data matrix and y the response. How can I implement the above in R?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the `optim` function. It can do unconstrained minimization using `method = 'L-BFGS-B'` and you can specify an analytical function to compute the gradient as well

EDIT. As Ben has pointed out correctly, `fminunc` does unconstrained optimization, which can also be achieved using the `optim` function choosing `Nelder-Mead` or `BFGS`. Moreover, I also noticed from the documentation of `fminunc` that it does large-scale optimization using `trust` region methods. There is an R package `trust` that I believe does the same thing. I would recommend taking a look at the `optimization` [task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) of R.

Comment: I'm confused, I thought that the OP was asking for *unconstrained* optimization and you are describing *constrained* optimization ... ?  (Not that it matters that much, `optim` is the right answer in any case.)

Comment: you are right! i dont know for some reason i assumed he was asking for unconstrained optimization. i have added an edit pointing the same.

Answer (score 1):

In the R, you can use the function `nlminb` in the R to do constrained optimization!

`nlminb(start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL, ..., scale = 1, control = list(), lower = -Inf, upper = Inf)`

The start is a vector include all initial value of parameters. objective is the cost function or any other function that you want to minimize.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `ucminf` function of the **ucminf** package? If yours is an unconstrained problem (and in many cases you can easily convert constrained problems into unconstrained ones), the `ucminf` is quite similar to Matlab's `fmincon`. The two are similar in the sense that both use a trust-region type monitoring. Unlike `fmincon` (that relies on the interior-point algorithm), `ucminf` is based on a quasi-Newton type of algorithm. However, `usminf` provides you with the same types of controls as `fmincon`. From my experience, `ucminf` is pretty good at replicating `fmincon`'s output, give it a shot.